# How do I fix monitor detection in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-media-center, hdmi, auto-detect

I'm using Windows 7 + Windows Media Center for my HTPC. It works great except from one annoying issue. Whenever I turn off my TV while listening to music, the music stops for a second or while Windows 7 tries to figure out what monitor is attached. After that second it settles down on a default 800x640. While not a big deal, it is annoying as I don't want to have the TV on while playing music.

Is there anyway to fix the monitor/disable monitor auto-detection on Windows 7 so it would not start recalibrating everything when I turn off my TV?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/120983/how-to-disable-monitor-auto-detection-in-windows-7

Answer (score 6):

This just in!   Block pin 19 on your hdmi cable with a small piece of electrical tape

like so

http://postimage.org/image/2g8p5dwdg/

This pin is responsible for sending on/off signals

Not my solution but I thought I would take a minute to propagate working intel as this solved the headache for me

Comment: Interesting! Where'd you hear or find this?

Comment: This works great.  You may need to use the "rigorous detection" feature in your graphics driver to initially detect the display.  Here is a thread with more details: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8a9b5aa7-fe33-4e6d-b39b-8ac80a21fdc2/disable-monitor-off-detection-how?forum=w7itprogeneral

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution but I don't know if it only works for me.

You have to setup in display/screen resolution your monitors(plasma whatever) to be generic non-pnp monitor

For example: I started Windows 7 with my monitor closed and  plasma didnt get recognized

And I didn't clicked on detect, I leaved the greyed out display and just select the  option:

`multiple displays:extend these displays`

I also did that before with my main display Sony CRT monitor.

So now I can start Windows with everything turn off and  when Windows 7 loads up and i  turn on my plasma and sony crt everything is in place

And doesnt get undetected.

If your generic non-pnp monitor doesnt give you resolutions you need you can create them (custom resolution) with Nvidia control panel.

Comment: Interesting. I know this is old, but would you mind expounding on this a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me.

Newest version of Catalyst Control Center as of today. 6-24-2014
Preferences - Advanced View

Left side column - Open My VGA Displays - Click on properties (VGA Display)

Uncheck EDID

Set display size and frequency. I recommend 60 hz unless you know for sure it can handle other frequencies as this is default for any monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the auto-detection feature of your graphics card through the advanced display properties or the driver management utility.

If yours is a ATI card, check the Catalyst Control Center:

[image]

Comment: Molly, thanks for answer. Sadly it doesn't work. BTW - which version of Catalyst is this? mine looks very different. (and yes I have an ATI radeon hd 4550 card).

Comment: since the screenshot shows a radeon x1800, i suppose it's about 3 or 4 years old. did you go through all options of the catalyst control center? i only have 1 ATI here, a radeon hd 4360, which happens to be in an older XP machine. ATI CCC requires dotnet frameworks which is a 'no no' for me so i can't check right now. :)

Comment: The latest CCC in windows 7 is very different, it also has some weird options hidden, light right clicking on the display icons in the desktop and graphics tab.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. I'm guessing the setting is purely for monitor detection within CCC. (...FYI, anyone who stumbles upon this -- I realize this is a 3+ year old thread)

Answer (score 1):

Add this reg entry by typing in regedit into the start search bar and hitting enter:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TMM]
"UseIViewHelper"=dword:00000000
@="0"
==========================================================================
```

or save:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TMM]
"UseIViewHelper"=dword:00000000
@="0"
```

in a **.reg** file (if your folder extensions are visible). If they're not - go to the folder you're in (Organize > Folder and Search Options) and enable "Show extensions for known file types".

You can now save this file as .txt and rename to .reg or whatever method you may choose to save this as a registry file.

When you double click on a registry file, it asks you if you want to enter this into the system registry - Say yes.

Comment: This doesn't work for 7, only for Vista

Comment: If you want to skip a step of Remaining to a .reg file when you are saving the text file You can put "'s around the name of the file to force the .reg type   for instance be default it will be [blah.text]  make it ["blah.reg"]

Answer (score 1):

open regedit and find

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Video{XXXX...}\0000
( 'XXXX' means device number. There are several device number folder and u should find 'AdapterDesc' in 0000 folder which key value is 'amd radeon HD 7XXX Series'. )

At that '0000' folder, Change 'PP_SclkDeepSleepDisable REG_DWORD' value 0 to 1.
and reboot!

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your services, the graphics card may have a service to detect this such as "AMD External Events Utility" or "ati hotkey poller". Disable it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have NVIDIA NVS 300 video card and stopping NVIDIA Windows services stopped this annoying behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me. Windows 7, NVidia Quadro NVS 295. But that's largely irrelevant.

The important part is, these are HP monitors EliteDisplay 241i.

Go to the on screen menu > Input Control > DP Hot-Plug Detection > switch it from Low Power to Always Active.

Doing this on both monitors has resolved the problem for me.
I suspect other monitors will have similar settings.